# Visual Basic reading text file

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013

VB is supposed to read each line and show only the corresponding "ItemNo" however what it does is read only the last line of my code and display that, it also does not return my message if i put in an item number that does not yet exist. What would be a way of correcting this so that it chooses only the line with the corresponding "ItemNo" and have it return my message when it fails to find the number.

```
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CheckNum.Click
    Dim File As String = "K:\Access to Computing Folder\Monday\Nicholas Kakou\Assignments\Assignment 2\MicroNut Software Ltd\MicroNut Software Ltd\Data Files\StockFile.dat"

    Dim TextLine As String = ""

    If System.IO.File.Exists(File) = True Then

        Dim objReader As New System.IO.StreamReader(File)

        Do While objReader.Peek() <> -1

            TextLine = objReader.ReadLine() & vbNewLine

        Loop
        MsgBox(TextLine)
    Else
        MsgBox("File Does Not Exist", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly)

    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: well, we are NOT going to be doing your homework. But what we can say is to step through your code to see what is going on. I can tell you firstly that you keep overwriting the TextLine variable on every line read thus the last line read is what you will get in your Message Box. (use MessageBox.Show and not MsgBox)

Comment: I was not asking you to do my "homework", I was asking where I was going wrong. Nowhere in my post does it say do this for me.

Comment: Sure but it was proposed like this. however I did give you a good headstart on why you get just the last line being displayed.... we want to make sure that you DO learn for your benefit... that's all. :)

Comment: I change my code to the way you suggested, however it still produces the same error. Where exactly should I remove the TextLine Variables?

Comment: which error? it works fine for me.... I don't think you did exactly what I suggested :) you are reading all the lines in the files, line by line. When it finishes reading, you display a msgbox - this will show the LAST line you read.

Comment: another way to approach Ahmed's response is to suggest that you move the first msgbox to be above the loop statement to better understand what is going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not very clear, but supposing that you are searching for a particular string in your text file then you could write this

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CheckNum.Click
    Dim FileName As String = ".........."
    If System.IO.File.Exists(FileName) = True Then
        Dim result = File.ReadLines(FileName)
        Dim line = result.Where(Function (x) x.Contains("ItemNo")).FirstOrDefault()
        If line Is Nothing Then 
             MsgBox.Show("Not Found")
        Else
             MsgBox.Show(line)
        End If
    Else
        MsgBox.Show("File Not Found")
    End If
End Sub
```

I have used a fixed string "ItemNo", you should change it to the variable that contains the search text

Notice the usage of [File.ReadLines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), this methods doesn't read the whole file in memory and allows to start to search the result collection using a lambda expression

Comment: I tried the code and i modified the variable, but then it throws this error at me "An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentNullException' occurred in System.Core.dll". I understand that it means it cannot find the variable but I have typed it exactly as I did in the .dat file. `If System.IO.File.Exists(FileName) = True Then
Dim result = ReadLines(FileName)
Dim line = result.Where(Function(x) x.Contains(" ItemNo:")).FirstOrDefault()
If line Is Nothing Then
MessageBox.Show("Not Found")
Else
MessageBox.Show(line)
End If
Else
MessageBox.Show("File Not Found")`

Comment: IF I do that it then says File is inaccessible due to it it's protection level (not being defined is what I understand from that expression)

Comment: Well, you could use System.IO.File.ReadLines(...) or add an Imports System.IO to avoid this unnecessary typing